# How to optimize the sum of squared values?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

How can we optimize the sum of squared values (or the sum of multiple absolute values)? I found that using ArgMin is very slow. Are there any other methods to accelerate the solution?

**Edit**：I am replicating a research paper, and the algorithm is roughly as follows：
let $$
u_M(\boldsymbol{x})=\sum_{i=1}^N \psi_i(\boldsymbol{x}) \sum_{j=1}^{J_n} u_{i j} \phi_{i j}(\boldsymbol{x}),
$$
$$
\operatorname{Loss}\left(\left\{u_{i, j, k}\right\}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\sum_{q=1}^Q\left\|\lambda_{i, q}^p\left(\mathcal{L} \boldsymbol{u}_M\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{i, q}\right)-\boldsymbol{f}\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{i, q}\right)\right)\right\|_2^2\right)+\left(\sum_{\boldsymbol{x}_{i, e} \in \partial \Omega}\left\|\lambda_{i, e}^b\left(\mathcal{B} \boldsymbol{u}_M\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{i, e}\right)-\boldsymbol{g}\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{i, e}\right)\right)\right\|_2^2\right)
$$The functions $\phi$ and $\psi$ are given and known.

The goal is to minimize the loss and obtain the optimal $u_{ij}$. In my code, $x_k$ is used to represent these $u_{ij}$. The number of $u_{ij}$ is adjustable, so there can be many $u_{ij}$.
For example, Loss is "total + bd1 + bd2 + bd3 + bd4"
[image]

```
test[x_, 
   y_] := -((3/2) Cos[\[Pi] x + (2 \[Pi]/5)] + 
      2 Cos[2 \[Pi] x - (\[Pi]/5)])*((3/
        2) Cos[\[Pi] y + (2 \[Pi]/5)] + 
     2 Cos[2 \[Pi] y - (\[Pi]/5)]);
Deltau[x_, y_] := Laplacian[test[x, y], {x, y}]
g1[x_] := test[x, y] /. y -> 0.
g2[x_] := test[x, y] /. y -> 1.
h1[y_] := test[x, y] /. x -> 0.
h2[y_] := test[x, y] /. x -> 1.
Laplacian[test[x, y], {x, y}];
D[D[test[x, y], y], y];


n = 2.;
dn = (2 n + 1)^2;
dj = 2.;
dq = 2.;
collocation = Tuples[Table[(i)/(2 n), {i, 0, 2 n}], 2];
random1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];
random2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];
random3 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];
random4 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];
random5 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dn, dj}];
omegapoint = 
  Table[{RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[1]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
      Min[collocation[[i]][[1]] + 1/(2 n), 1.]}], 
    RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[2]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
      Min[collocation[[i]][[2]] + 1/(2 n), 1.]}]}, {i, 1, dn}, {q, 1, 
    dq}];

f[i_, j_, x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{(1 + Sin[2 \[Pi] (x - collocation[[i]][[j]]) 2 n])/
      2, -5/4 <= (x - collocation[[i]][[j]]) 2 n <= -3/4}, {1, -3/
       4 <= (x - collocation[[i]][[j]]) 2 n <= 
      3/4}, {(1 - Sin[2 \[Pi] (x - collocation[[i]][[j]]) 2 n])/2, 
     3/4 <= (x - collocation[[i]][[j]]) 2 n <= 5/4}}];
psi[i_, x_, y_] := f[i, 1, x]*f[i, 2, y];
li[i_, x_, 
   y_] := {(x - collocation[[i]][[1]]) 2 n, (y - 
      collocation[[i]][[2]]) 2 n};
phi[i_, j_, x_, y_] := 
  Tanh[{random1[[i, j]], random2[[i, j]]} . li[i, x, y] + 
    random5[[i, j]]];
df[x_, y_] := 
  Table[phi[i, j, x, y]*psi[i, x, y], {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, dj}] // 
   Flatten;
dd1 = D[D[df[x, y], x], x];
dd2 = D[D[df[x, y], y], y];



xVars = ToExpression[Table["x" <> ToString[i], {i, 1, dn dj}]];
omegapointbd1 = 
  Table[{RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[1]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
      Min[collocation[[i]][[1]] + 1/(2 n), 1]}], 0.}, {i, 1, dn}, {q, 
    1, dq}];
omegapointbd2 = 
  Table[{RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[1]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
      Min[collocation[[i]][[1]] + 1/(2 n), 1]}], 1.}, {i, 1, dn}, {q, 
    1, dq}];
omegapointbd3 = 
  Table[{0, 
    RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[2]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
      Min[collocation[[i]][[2]] + 1/(2 n), 1.]}]}, {i, 1, dn}, {q, 1, 
    dq}];
omegapointbd4 = 
  Table[{1, 
    RandomReal[{Max[collocation[[i]][[2]] - 1/(2 n), 0.], 
      Min[collocation[[i]][[2]] + 1/(2 n), 1.]}]}, {i, 1, dn}, {q, 1, 
    dq}];
max = Table[
    Abs[dd1 + dd2] /. {x -> omegapoint[[i, j]][[1]], 
      y -> omegapoint[[i, j]][[2]]}, {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, dq}]; // Timing
max1 = Table[
   Abs[df[x, y]] /. {x -> omegapointbd1[[i, j]][[1]], 
     y -> omegapointbd1[[i, j]][[2]]}, {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, dq}];
max2 = Table[
   Abs[df[x, y]] /. {x -> omegapointbd2[[i, j]][[1]], 
     y -> omegapointbd2[[i, j]][[2]]}, {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, dq}];
max3 = Table[
   Abs[df[x, y]] /. {x -> omegapointbd3[[i, j]][[1]], 
     y -> omegapointbd3[[i, j]][[2]]}, {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, dq}];
max4 = Table[
   Abs[df[x, y]] /. {x -> omegapointbd4[[i, j]][[1]], 
     y -> omegapointbd4[[i, j]][[2]]}, {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, dq}];

lambda = 100/Table[Max[max[[i, j]]], {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, dq}];
lambda1 = 100/Table[Max[max1[[i, j]]], {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, dq}];
lambda2 = 100/Table[Max[max2[[i, j]]], {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, dq}];
lambda3 = 100/Table[Max[max3[[i, j]]], {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, dq}];
lambda4 = 100/Table[Max[max4[[i, j]]], {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, dq}];


total = Total[
    Catenate[
     Table[lambda[[i, 
         j]] Abs[((dd1 + dd2) . 
            xVars - ((8 \[Pi]^2 Cos[\[Pi]/5 - 2 \[Pi] x] + 
                3/2 \[Pi]^2 Sin[\[Pi]/10 - \[Pi] x]) (2 Cos[\[Pi]/5 - 
                   2 \[Pi] y] + 
                3/2 Sin[\[Pi]/10 - \[Pi] y]) + (-2 Cos[\[Pi]/5 - 
                   2 \[Pi] x] - 
                3/2 Sin[\[Pi]/10 - \[Pi] x]) (-8 \[Pi]^2 Cos[\[Pi]/
                   5 - 2 \[Pi] y] - 
                3/2 \[Pi]^2 Sin[\[Pi]/10 - \[Pi] y]))) /. {x -> 
           omegapoint[[i, j]][[1]], 
          y -> omegapoint[[i, j]][[2]]}], {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, 
       dq}]]]; // Timing

bd1 = Total[
   Catenate[
    Table[lambda1[[i, 
        j]] Abs[((df[x, y] . xVars - g1[x])) /. {x -> 
          omegapointbd1[[i, j]][[1]], y -> 0.}], {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, 
      dq}]]];
bd2 = Total[
   Catenate[
    Table[lambda2[[i, 
        j]] Abs[((df[x, y] . xVars - g2[x])) /. {x -> 
          omegapointbd2[[i, j]][[1]], y -> 1. }], {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, 
      dq}]]];

bd3 = Total[
   Catenate[
    Table[lambda3[[i, 
        j]] Abs[((df[x, y] . xVars - h1[y])) /. {x -> 0., 
         y -> omegapointbd3[[i, j]][[2]]}], {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, 
      dq}]]];
bd4 = Total[
    Catenate[
     Table[lambda4[[i, 
         j]] Abs[((df[x, y] . xVars - h2[y])) /. {x -> 1., 
          y -> omegapointbd4[[i, j]][[2]]}], {i, 1, dn}, {j, 1, 
       dq}]]]; // Timing

uop = ArgMin[total + bd1 + bd2 + bd3 + bd4, xVars, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 5]; // Timing

opdf[x_, y_] := df[x, y] . uop;
D[D[opdf[x, y], x], x] + D[D[opdf[x, y], y], y] - 
  D[D[test[x, y], x], x] + D[D[test[x, y], y], y] /. {x -> 0.5, 
  y -> 0.5}
```

Comment: Please share code as text, not images, and include any attempts at a solution you have made so far.

Comment: What "graph below"?

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you very much, I just provided the specific code as well as a general description of the problem.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thank you very much, I just provided the specific code as well as a general description of the problem.

Comment: Delete your phrase "graph below" as there is *no graph below*.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork thanks, I  delete the phrase "graph below".